# Visualizing dynamic 3D models with qml and qt

Tags: qt, 3d, qml, qtquick2, graph-visualization

This question concerns an qt quick 2 application.
In the qt/qml documentation, a lot information can be found on how to include a static model from an external source into a 3DScene. However, I did not find any examples on how to build and visualize a model on the fly.

More specifically, I want to visualize an [arrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrangement_(space_partition)). I already have a data structure holding the arrangement (using a library called [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/)). The arrangements I'll be concerned with have 3 primitive types: nodes, segments and faces. The nodes reside in 3D space and the number of nodes could reach a few thousands. I would like to know the following:

- How to visualize a user build arrangement
- How to automatically update the visualization if the underlying data structure has been changed
- How to support user input to this visualization (like selecting a node/edge/face, or selecting two nodes to add an edge between them)

What would be the best way to do this? What classes/types should I implement? Any pointers to existing examples/tutorials? I prefer to use QML as much as I can.